# How to evaluate a collection size(Set) in evaluate expression in spring webflow

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

My flow file has view state as below:

```
<view-state id="shopstate">
<on-entry>
<evaluate expression="MyShop.getProducts.size()" result="flowScope.noOfProducts"/>
</on-entry>
</view-state id="shopstate">
```

**Note**: Here Myshop class has a method `getProducts()` which returns the set. And I have mocked the Myshop in my webflow junit as well.

Following is the webflow junit test method:

```
   @Test
   public void testMyShopProducts()
   {
          Set<String> products = new HashSet<String>();
          products.add("Mobiles");
          products.add("Tabs");
          startFlow(context);
          context.setEventId("shopstate");
          when(Myshop.getProducts.size()).thenReturn(products.size());

   }
```

**Error:**

when I run the this test method, I got error as below

> [main] ERROR c.b.h.c.e.ShopException - org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@c789fb targetAction = [EvaluateAction@df2940 expression = Myshop.getProducts.size(), resultExposer = [ActionResultExposer@10d4f27 result = flowScope.noOfProducts, resultType = [null]]], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'shopstate' of flow 'details' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'.

I have tried in many ways but in vain.
Can you let me know if there is any other way to do it please?

Comment: I assume the error is being generated by `startFlow()`? You have to specify the `when()` _before_ it'd be called, not after.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But still the same when i kept startFlow() before.Can you tell me is it the correct approach that i am following to find the Size of products in evaluate expression?

Comment: What I meant is, put `when(Myshop.getProducts.size()).thenReturn(products.size());` before `startFlow(context);`. I'm honestly not sure if you can even do that with `when()`, anyway. I would just suggest something like `when(Myshop.getProducts()).thenReturn(products);`, and just allow the native `size()` function to do its thing.

Comment: I have tried as you said.    when(Myshop.getProducts()).thenReturn(products); but no luck.Is there any other alternative for this?

Comment: You did move the `when()` to a point before it'd be called, right? And, just to verify the basics, `Myshop` is a mocked object, right?